# Ignite start with "Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize="

Tags: ignite

My ignite server have 128G RAM, with Xmx 10G off-heap 70G, when start, the log shows:

```
[11:30:27,376][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
[11:30:27,377][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[11:30:27,377][INFO][main][IgniteKernal]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
```

I have search web, and i found this article said it is not necessary to configure MaxDirectMemorySize, http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Do-we-require-to-set-MaxDirectMemorySize-JVM-parameter-td21200.html
and some articles says the default MaxDirectMemorySize will be same as Xmx, so what should i configure for this option, i am just confused, and if it is no useful, why ignite dump that suggestion log to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an indication of failure, you can just ignore this suggestion unless your node/cluster failing due to OOM in direct buffer memory. This is an option to give you ability to control how many direct memory could be allocated, otherwise it is controlled using default direct memory policy by JVM you are using. Ignite only checks if it's set in JVM options.

Do you experience any issues with OOME in direct buffer memory in your app?

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanations, i am a newbie of java also, so i have no experience of OOME of direct memory.

Answer (score 0):

Direct buffer memory is used by some file operations (like read and write) when the program calls functions from the NIO libray.

Due to a bug, its value if not specified and you set Xmx ... it is copied from Xmx.

Direct buffer memory default is 64 Mb (if you don't set it ans also don't set Xmx).

I suggest MaxDirectMemorySize=64 or 256 Mb

Bigger values: perhaps you don't see errors, but I doubt you get better performance.